# Use Lambda Expression within ASP.NET MVC View using VB.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, lambda

With ASP.NET MVC 1.0, .NET 3.5 and C# you can easily pass a method a lambda expression that will do  a "Response.Write" some content when it's executed within the method:

```
<% Html.SomeExtensionMethod(
    () => { <%
        <p>Some page content<p>
    %> }
) %>
```

The method signature is similar to this:

```
public void SomeExtensionMethod(this HtmlHelper helper, Action pageContent)
{
    pageContent();
}
```

Does anyone know how to peforma a similar call using Lambda expressions in VB.NET using the same method signature shown above?

I've tried the following in VB.NET, but it wont work:

```
<% Html.SomeExtensionMethod(New Action( _
    Function() %> <p>Some Content</p> <% _
    )) %>
```

I get an exception saying "Expression Expected."

Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong? How do you do this in VB.NET?

Comment: use reflector. [who doesn't hate char count limit]

Comment: Wondering - what's the use case of such a method? What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This comes in very handy with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: This is also a very simplified use case, not the full usage scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB.NET 9.0 doesn't support multi-statement lambda expressions or anonymous methods. It also [does not support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) lambda expression that does not return a value meaning that you cannot declare an anonymous function of type [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx).

Otherwise this works but is meaningless because the lambda does nothing:

```
<% Html.SomeExtensionMethod(New Action(Function() "<p>Some Content</p>"))%>
```

Now let's take your example:

```
<% Html.SomeExtensionMethod(New Action( _
    Function() %> <p>Some Content</p> <% _
)) %>
```

Should be translated to something like this:

```
Html.SomeExtensionMethod(New Action(Function() Html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.Write("<p>Some Content</p>")))
```

which doesn't compile in VB.NET 9.0 because your expression doesn't return a value.

In VB.NET 10 [you will be able to use the Sub keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253(VS.100).aspx):

```
Html.SomeExtensionMethod(New Action(Sub() Html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.Write("<p>Some Content</p>")))
```

which will compile fine.

Comment: this is not true in 3.5 and 4.0. VB has support for lambdas in the newer versions of ASP.NET

Comment: Jason, How do you do this in 3.5 or 4.0?

Comment: Darin, you state that the lambda does nothing in the code you posted. What it does is allow for deferred execution; which can be very handy in some situations.

Comment: @Jason, I didn't say that VB.NET does not support lambda expressions. I say that currently (VB.NET 10) does not support multi-statement lambda expressions.

Comment: A little rectification to my last comment: VB.NET 10 will support multi-line lambda expression. VB.NET 9.0 doesn't.

Comment: It seems that this is one way that C# is superior to VB.NET

Comment: @Chris: As much as i would like to believe you are wrong, i am afraid i have to agree with you on that one. And that is coming from a VB.NET programmer.... :-(